# android dev app not updating with changes on cordova

Tags: android, cordova, android-studio

I have seen several questions similar to this, but none of the accepted answers have worked for me. I've tried deleting the apk folder, adding no cache meta tags to the html (which doesn't update anyway), incrementing the android version number, incrementing the app version number, incrementing the javascript file version number in the script tag; I've tried uninstalling the android platform and reinstalling; I've uninstalled the app from my phone repeatedly; I've run `cordova clean` over and over again, I've tried deleting all the `www` folders in the `platform/android` directory. I've even started the app from scratch after a clean install of cordova.

No matter what I do, the changes I make to index.html or index.js do not update on my android phone. Even when it's clear they've updated everywhere in the build files, and the apk has to be recreated because I manually deleted it, my phone pulls up the app exactly as it was on my first test build. Not a single change has ever been updated on the android platform. Except, the version number will change, just not the html or javascript files themselves.

The ios platform updates just fine, as does the browser platform, obviously.

I'm using the cordova cli, no phonegap app, just pure cordova in terminal.

**I'm on mac osx high sierra, with the latest android studio.**

```
adb is 1.0.39.
cordova 8.0.
node 9.3.
javac 1.8.0_151.
ant 1.10.1.
homebrew 1.4.3.
```

**update** i also just tried removing the `index.html` and `index.js` files and replacing them with bare bones, essentially empty files (basic declarations in the html file). I ran `cordova clean` and then `cordova run android --device` and the app installed on my android, with the original index files. I.e., still not updating changed content, even brand new files.

Answer (score 0):

Confirmed resolution: after a clean install and a one-by-one addition of my plugins, with html updates in between each plugin install, I've confirmed that the issue was an incompatibility with the `android-fingerprint-auth` plugin. Without that installed, I get a proper updates on the android app. If I install that plugin and then uninstall it, updates continue not to work. I.e., it does some permanent damage to the app.